# External Hard Drive not accessible Raw in disk management but ntfs detect when lauch chckdisk

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs, chkdsk

I can't access my external hard drive.
it's looks like a corrupted filesystem problem but I don't know how to fix it.
please fine bellow my chkdsk log.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> chkdsk /f d:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Elements.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
with type code B0 in file 0.
  1704960 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  9130 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  2259 reparse records processed.
  1779338 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
  2259 reparse records processed.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
  37190 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
Usn Journal verification completed.
Correcting errors in the Master File Table (MFT) mirror.

Windows has made corrections to the file system.
No further action is required.

1953479679 KB total disk space.
1896834944 KB in 405447 files.
    135712 KB in 37191 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   1862735 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  54646288 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 488369919 total allocation units on disk.
  13661572 allocation units available on disk.
```

Comment: Have you run Testdisk on the drive?

Comment: I'm trying this right now, and it can browse all the files. but the copy take years!!! It's been already 2 days a launch the copy. I don't know why...

Comment: Probably because the disk is broken.

Answer (score 2):

CHKDSK in Windows 10 version 1803 is botched / broken. If you use a CHKDSK from an earlier version it will repair your station. That version of CHKDSK will say 176 in file 0 instead of B0 in file 0.

See also https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/chkdsk-does-not-repair-bad-attribute-list-entry-in/86de6773-9f8c-4ac0-b8d7-e93389a8c34f

Comment: OP does not say he is using Windows 10.

Comment: You're right, I don't know if OP uses Windows 10. We'll only know for sure if OP responds/elaborates/marks as answer etcetera.
I guess I assumed too much yesterday evening, in my elated mood when my own problem in CHKDSK with "type code B0 in file 0" in Windows 10 was solved by using an older version.